# What is the name of this UI menu?

Tags: menu, terminology, categorization, component

What is the name of this kind of tree menu where descending levels of the tree are shown in panels from left to right. The tree is navigated by *clicking* elements.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Whatever it's called, it has some UX issues. [This article talks about those issues and what some folks do about them.](http://bjk5.com/post/44698559168/breaking-down-amazons-mega-dropdown)

Comment: This is *not* a drop down. It's a fixed element in the page and it is navigated by clicking, not hovering.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These are referred to as **[Miller Columns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller_columns)**.

[image]